# asp.net manually lock user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net web site with oauth2 authentification. I need to manually lock/unlock users permanently but I can't find standart method in ApplicationUser. The closest thing I could have done is setting LockoutEndDateUtc like this

```
user.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.Now.AddYears(100);
```

But this is kinda gimmicky. Is there standard way of doing this? Am I getting something wrong. If I can manipulate these things from outside why isn't there just Lock/Unlock method or IsLocked property?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are getting your use base from DB; probably a `users` table (for example). You can have a column like `IsLocked bit`. While checking against DB check for that `IsLocked` and if `true` and then deny login of user and throw a message saying you are locked.

Comment: Thanks, didn't want to modify DB structure. It Just seemed strange to me that I can lock users by playing with other variables but there is no simple obvious way to do this